# Empty paragraphs around figure and figcaption tags when using markdown

Tags: post-editor, html5, markdown

I'm using WP 3.8 and [Markdown on Save Improved](http://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-on-save-improved/) plugin and have following code for outputing HTML5 tags when inserting images via Media Uploader:

```
function html5_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
  $src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size, false );
  $html5 = "<figure>";
  $html5 .= "<img src='$src[0]' alt='$alt' />";
  if ($caption) {
    $html5 .= "<figcaption>$caption</figcaption>";
  }
  $html5 .= "</figure>";
  return $html5;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

And in editor output is fine, but on publish my code looks like this:

```
<p></p>
<figure>
<img src="image_link" alt="alt_txt">
<p></p>
<figcaption>caption_txt</figcaption>
<p></p>
</figure>
<p></p>
```

If I put `div` wrapper around `figure` then there are no empty paragraphs but I'm wondering why figure and figcaption aren't recognized as block elements? Also, this doesn't happen with [wp-markdown](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-markdown/) plugin so it seems it's not markdown problem since both plugins use same parser.

When combining HTML and markdown in other ways, output is fine so I think that's not the issue.

Comment: Please update your installation before proceeding further. Current is 3.8 and as core doesn't support older versions...

Comment: I finally got around to updating to 3.8 and testing again. Nothing's changed, problem remains...

Comment: I guess that's a problem with `wpautop()`. Have you already asked the plugin author?

Comment: yes, I posted question wp forums a while ago but got no response http://wordpress.org/support/topic/empty-paragraphs-around-figure-and-figcaption-tags